# OneDrive for business Client sync Sharepoint Library with Read-only permissions

Tags: sharepoint, onedrive

Office 365 / Sharepoint Libraries
OneDrive for business Client
Windows 7

I was testing out Syncing capabilities of OneDrive for business client for users with only Read-Only permissions.

When a user has Read-only permissions the Sync button on the Sharepoint library site does not show itself.  But I was able to copy the URL and manually Sync the library through the OneDrive for business client.

When doing this, the folder will Sync to the local client.

If the user deletes a file, it will temporarily be deleted out of the client's sync folder, but it does not delete from the Sharepoint library.

The next time it syncs, the file will be pulled back down to the client, but this time without a green check indicating fully synced (it looks like a regular file in the folder).

If the user deletes the file again, the next Sync cycle will NOT pull the file back to the client.

I tried editing the file once in the Sharepoint Library as the next step, and the File synced back to the client.

If the client deleted it, it would not get pulled back to the client.

If I tried editing, or overwriting the file the problem was not resolved.

If I un-synced and re-synced the library the problem is rectified.

My question: Is this working as intended? Or is there a proper sequence of events to always force the file to be re-uploaded to the client?

Thanks,
Dennis